# How can I filter buffer-list to only show buffers not visible in windows

Tags: elisp

I'd like the this function to not return buffers visible in windows.

i.e. I want to eliminate any buffers hanging out in my current frame from the results.

I know that the function 'window-list' returns buffers visible in windows, but I wasn't sure how to make window-list a predicate to the -filter function.

```
(defun projectile-project-buffers-non-visible ()
  "Get a list of non visible project buffers."
  (let ((project-root (projectile-project-root)))
    (-filter (lambda (buffer)
               (projectile-project-buffer-p buffer project-root))
(buffer-list))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this? For each buffer, look at whether it is displayed by a window. If not, return it.

```lisp
(defun not-visible-buffers (buffers)
  "given a list of buffers, return buffers which are not currently visible"
  (remove nil
        (mapcar
         '(lambda (buf)
        (unless (get-buffer-window-list buf) buf))
         buffers)
        ))
```

You could call it as follows:

```
(not-visible-buffers (buffer-list))
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this works, but I'll leave this open in case anyone has a more elegant solution.

```
  (defun projectile-project-buffers-non-visible ()
    "Get a list of non visible project buffers."
    (let ((project-root (projectile-project-root)))
      (-filter (lambda (buffer)
                 (and
                  (projectile-project-buffer-p buffer project-root)
                  (not (get-buffer-window buffer 'visible))))
               (buffer-list)
               )))
```